# Configuración de routers, Realizar multiples conexiones con WDS de wifi

Tags: router, wifi

Hola que tal? tengo 10 routers tl-wr841nd, y los quiero utilizar Tecnología WDS para que se conecten entre si, y brinden una red amplia de wifi, sin cables

La tecnología WDS es para compartir la misma wifi, a través de varios routers, Aqui una breve explicación de como configurarlo
https://www.tp-link.com/en/support/faq/227/

En fin, Mi idea seria que al router colocarle la siguiente configuración
WAN : detectar automaticamente la ip
LAN : 192.168.1.1 / 255.255.255.0
DHCP servidor: 192.168.1.1 A 192.168.1.200
WIFI: Fiestadejuegos
Contraseña: juguemos
seguridad : WPK2/Personal
Encriptacion: AES
Canal: 2

En los clientes routers "repetidores" un LAN IP por arriba de 200, es decir
192.168.1.201, 192.168.1.202 y así sucesivamente:
Activo WDS en los repetidores y los coloco en cadena, uno detrás de otro formando una línea , con el misma configuración WIFI, y todos apuntando el BSSID : del router maestro y el DHCP desactivado

entre los router puedo navegar como si estuvieran en red, al ingresar a sus ips por el navegador, pero al ir al segundo router concatenado, me dice "Error al obtener ip" y no brinda ip. He intentado cambiar, los BSSID y colocárselo al que esta delante, de cada router, y es el mismo problema
A partir del segundo router concatenado no entrega ip de DHCP! podría alguien ayudarme con experiencia en redes? espero respuesta muchas gracias

Comment: El rango DHCP incluye al ruteador raíz, debería quedar fuera. ¿Ya hay clientes conectados a la red? ¿Cuántas IPs han sido asignadas?

Comment: Ahi lo aclaro bien,el servidor DHCP lo configuro de 1 a 100, y llos repetidores por arriba del 200, bien claro, eso no hara interferencia, esta todo ahi, escrito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Problema que tenia es que los FIREWALL interferían con el servicio de DHCP, simplemente desactivando los firewall pude hacer todo, con una correcta configuración, los firewall eran los que impedían comunicar el servidor dhcp entre si, espero que le sirva a alguien!